# Comala/Confluence - allow one user to edit page without transition

Tags: workflow, confluence, document-management

I have a Comala workflow page. At the final stage an automation user must be able to edit content of the page. But this action triggers "update" transition and all of the approvals roll back.
How can I set specific user to be an exception and not to trigger "update" when editing page ?

I thought about alternative ways to do this. Maybe Restricting edit of page on final state for everyone except User and removing update transition?

Answer (score 0):

This works:
Technical state with trigger, that depends on user. If user in whitelist, return to aproved state. If not return to draft state.

```
  {state:UPDATED_1|hidefrompath=true}
    {state}
    {state:Aproved by all|final=true|updated=UPDATED_1|hideselection=true}
    {state}
    {trigger:statechanged|state=UPDATED_1|user=user1,user2}
        {set-state:Aproved by all}
    {trigger}
    {trigger:statechanged|state=UPDATED_1|user=!user1,user2}
        {set-state:Draft}
    {trigger}
```